# should Stripe be integrated in frontend or backend ? (React+Django Rest )

Tags: reactjs, django, stripe-payments

just a bit confused as i found both solutions after a day of research.

some suggest to use "pip install dj-stripe" and add keys and other options in "settings.py". Then the script in frontend to get redirect button

and some suggest the use of "npm install --save @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js", and add keys in "app.js" or a designated js file.

i would like to know if it differs (security ,efficiency,.. wise), or is there a concrete way of doing it (best practice way) and how,

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, depending on which key your referring to.

> **Publishable API** keys are meant solely to identify your account with
> Stripe, they aren’t secret. In other words, you can safely publish
> them in places like your Stripe.js JavaScript code, or in an Android
> or iPhone app.
>
> **Secret** You must keep your secret API keys confidential
> and only store them on your own servers. You must not share your
> secret API key with any third parties. Your account’s secret API key
> can perform any API request to Stripe without restriction. If Stripe
> believes that your secret API key has been compromised, we may cancel
> and reissue it, potentially resulting in an interruption to your
> Stripe services.

Comment: No problem. I recall it being a bit confusing for me as well. There are operations that you may want to initiate on the client and others from the server. Depends on your requirements.